# Getting a DialogFragment to instantiate

Tags: java, android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I am new to Android.
Trying to show a dialog on press of a button like below using DialogFragments

File : Dialog2/LoginDialog.java

```
package com.kartnet.Dialog2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;

public class LoginDialog extends DialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder ad_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        //ad_builder.setMessage(R.string.login_dialog);
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener ad_listener =
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg1, int id) {
                final String tag = "CustomDlg";
                Log.d(tag, id + " clicked");
            }
        };

        ad_builder.setTitle(R.string.btn_dialog_custom_title);
        LayoutInflater linf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        ad_builder.setView(linf.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null));

        ad_builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", ad_listener);
        ad_builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", ad_listener);
        return ad_builder.create();
    }

}
```

File : Dialog2/Dialog2App.java

```
package com.kartnet.Dialog2;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;

public class Dialog2App extends Activity
{
    /* Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
public void displayDialogCustom(View v)
{
    LoginDialog ld = new LoginDialog(); /*<<=== FAILS with runtime exception */
    // ld.show(getFragmentManager(), "login_dialog");
}   /* displayCustomDialog */
}
```

Why should it fail at runtime, with no errors during compile time? Also, since both files are declared to be in the same package (com.kartnet.Dialog2), is there anything special I need to get these two java files to be in the application?

Here is what the error displayed

```
I/ActivityManager(   69): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.kartnet.Dialog2/.Dialog2App } from pid 210
I/ActivityManager(   69): Start proc com.kartnet.Dialog2 for activity com.kartnet.Dialog2/.Dialog2App: pid=1328 uid=10034 gids={1015}
W/dalvikvm( 1328): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/kartnet/Dialog2/LoginDialog; (7)
W/dalvikvm( 1328): Link of class 'Lcom/kartnet/Dialog2/LoginDialog;' failed
E/dalvikvm( 1328): Could not find class 'com.kartnet.Dialog2.LoginDialog', referenced from method com.kartnet.Dialog2.Dialog2App.displayDialogCustom
W/dalvikvm( 1328): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 25 (Lcom/kartnet/Dialog2/LoginDialog;) in Lcom/kartnet/Dialog2/Dialog2App;
D/dalvikvm( 1328): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
D/dalvikvm( 1328): VFY: dead code 0x0002-0005 in Lcom/kartnet/Dialog2/Dialog2App;.displayDialogCustom (Landroid/view/View;)V
I/ActivityManager(   69): Displayed com.kartnet.Dialog2/.Dialog2App: +1s956ms
D/dalvikvm(  317): GC_EXPLICIT freed 19K, 55% free 2588K/5703K, external 1625K/2137K, paused 3208ms
D/AndroidRuntime( 1328): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1328): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2144)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2139)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.kartnet.Dialog2.LoginDialog
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    at com.kartnet.Dialog2.Dialog2App.displayDialogCustom(Dialog2App.java:104)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1328):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Have you added both files in the manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the attached log, it appears you're trying to run the code on an older device which does not offer native support to `Fragment`s:

> Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/kartnet/Dialog2/LoginDialog;

Above basically means that `android.app.DialogFragment` could not be resolved, which will happen on pre-Honeycomb (< Android 3.0 / API level 11) devices. You were probably looking for the backwards compatible `Fragment` classes that are part of the support library (in the `android.support.v4.app.*` package).

To migrate your code to the classes in the support libary, you should:

1. [Set up the support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).
2. Change all `android.app.DialogFragment` references to `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment` (and also any other `Fragment` classes you may be using).
3. Change your `Activity` to a `FragmentActivity` (also located in the support libary).

Comment: I will try this one and update you. Looks like this is very much possible because I am using ap level 10. I am moving to 4.3 api level 18. For some reason, every time I change a setting in android avd, it reset the api level to the lowest available.

Comment: Yes. That was exactly what was happening. Thanks a lot for pointing out the api level mismatch. Now I can see what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this dialog manager to display simple dialogs.

```
public class AlertDialogManager {
/**
 * Function to display simple Alert Dialog
 * @param context - application context
 * @param title - alert dialog title
 * @param message - alert message
 * @param status - success/failure (used to set icon)
 *               - pass null if you don't want icon
 * */
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
        Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    if(status != null)
        // Setting alert dialog icon
        alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

In your activity you can use this

```
alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,"Header","Message", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`Properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export` and check Android Private Libraries

Comment: Hm... I don't use Eclipse. In fact, I use only vim/gvim :-) and ant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create the dialog before you return it with

```
Dialog d = ad_builder.create();
```

`return d;`

to see if it fail to create the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

DialogFragment are singletons, so you cannot do:

```
LoginDialog ld = new LoginDialog(); /*<<=== FAILS with runtime exception */
```

you should use LoginDialog.instantiate(...) method